# Illustrator Path Won't Cut

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point

A path I created by converting a guide to a path will not open. Tried the eraser tool, the cut path option in the anchor menu to no avail. When the path is only 2 nodes long a random non-selectable segment is created to close the path.

AI [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xl2wyv-4026zpYAUA37m56BuX1N4q5TZ/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Attached the result of using the eraser tool.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select the object and open the Appearance panel you will see an "Add" effect applied to it.

Select the effect, then click and drag it to the trash in the Appearance panel. Now, you will be able to select the segment with the Direct Selection Tool <kbd>A</kbd>, and hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

[image]

Note: Any time you see some inexplicable/unselectable thing in Illustrator, the first place to head is the Appearance panel, to find out what is really going on.

Answer (score 0):

Dig out the Scissors under the eraser and use it. Have View > Snap to point =ON to be able to cut exactly at the corner point.

The Eraser removes a part of the closed area and generates a new edge, it's purpose isn't to slice curves nor remove segments.